# UICollectionView Crash?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to use a `UICollectionView` in collaboration with a `UICollectionViewCell` to display thumbnails of images. The `UICollectionViewCell`'s used in my app are custom (simplistic) subclasses:

```
#import "MemeCell.h"

@implementation MemeCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

}
return self;
}

-(void)setThumb:(UIImage *)image {
    if (_thumb != image) {
        _thumb = image;
    }

    _imageThumb.image = _thumb;
}

@end
```

And in the `File's Owner` of my `UICollectionView`, I use:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static BOOL nibLoaded = NO;

if (!nibLoaded) {
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MemeCell" bundle:nil];
    [_collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MemeCell"];
    nibLoaded = YES;
}

MemeCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MemeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *path = [_imageThumbs objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageNamed:path];
[cell setThumb:thumb];

return cell;
}
```

to return a cell. The view works fine when it is first presented, but after dismissing itself from it's delegate calling `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`, it cannot be presented again without crashing with a

```
2013-03-10 22:11:35.448 CapifyPro[21115:907] -[UICollectionViewCell setThumb:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e593320
2013-03-10 22:11:35.450 CapifyPro[21115:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell setThumb:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e593320'
```

Can anyone provide insight?

Comment: The error message is saying that you're trying to send setThumb to a UICollectionViewCell, not your custom cell. Are you doing anything in IB with this cell, or have you registered a class or nib for the cell?

Comment: I register a class in `viewDidLoad`, and changed the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to my edited post

Comment: Try taking out that if(! nibLoaded) clause, and register the nib instead of the class. Then, if there's no cell to dequeue, the system automatically gets one from the nib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use use UICollectionViewCell by XIB or storyBoardCell. simple drag drop your imageThumb imageView to MemeCell.h. Delete your setter inside MemeCell.m. Then set in dequence:

```
MemeCell *cell = (MemeCell*) [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MemeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageThumb.image = [UIImage imageNamed:path]
```

In the case MemeCell no Xib. please init and add imageThumb as subview of memeCell.contentView.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
     self.imageThumb = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
     [self.contentView addSubviews:self.imageThumb];

}
return self;
}
```

*Edit: If you just store your thumbImage, don't display, just declare in Cell.h, don't need to rewrite setter.

```
property(strong,nonomatic) UIImage *thumbImage;
```